# kubectl get all deployments with specific image tag

Tags: kubectl

I have a question. how to find all deployments in cluster with specific tag image.
I want something like that:

```
kubectl get deployment -A -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}'
```

But with deployments names and with specific image tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a cluster available to try this.

You don't want to `range` but `filter` and I think (!?) you won't be able to use `kubectl`'s `JSONPath` to:

1. filter only `${TAG}` from `image: ${REPO}:${TAG}` but you can filter by the value of a field e.g. `${REPO}:${TAG}`
2. Return the deployments' `metadata.name` values

IIRC you can't nest `filter`, so you can't `item[?(@.spec.template.spec.containers[?(@.image=\"${IMAGE}\")].metadata.name`

You can enumerate same-level fields e.g. `container.name` if that helps. I haven't tried this but:

```sh
IMAGE="..."

FILTER="{
  .items[*].spec.template.spec.containers[?(@.image==\"${IMAGE}\")].name
}"

kubectl \
get deployments \
--all-namespaces \
--output=jsonpath="${FILTER}"
```

This may be better done with a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```sh
IMAGE="..."

FILTER="
.items[]|
  select(.spec.template.spec.containers[].image==\"${IMAGE}\")
  .metadata.name
"

kubectl \
get deployments \
--all-namespaces \
--output=json \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

> **NOTE** Using `jq` you can filter by `${TAG}` too. I'll leave that exercise to you.